# Pass a value from powershell to TFS Build Workflow

Tags: powershell, tfs, build-process

I have a build which kicks off a PowerShell script. What it does is gather code coverage metrics and then stores that info in a database. I'd like to pass a value out of that script and back into the build workflow so I can pass or fail the build based on that value.

Any ideas on how I could accomplish that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to have PowerShell throw an exception. That will also cause Powershell to return a non-0 exit code. In your `InvokeProcess` you can either handle the Error stream or have the `Result` parameter assigned to a variable on your build workflow, then follow that with an if block to pass or fail the build.

Or you can return the coverage outcome using the `exit` function, it will be assigned to the `Result` property of the `InvokeProcess` Activity.

```
exit 12345;
```

Comment: Would it be possible to create custom error code, this way I can isolate it from real errors? Hope that made sense.

Comment: How about this option? Pass in the coverage threshold value to PowerShell, the coverage process would run, and if the passed in value was less than the result, I could set the build status from within PowerShell.

Comment: Sure, that's possible as well, call the `exit` function from powershell: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2006/10/14/windows-powershell-exit-codes.aspx

Comment: This is what I came up with on the PowerShell side:

`function CoverageResult()
{
    IF ($CoveragePercent -lt $FailurePercent) 
    {
        Write-Output "Exit Code 10000: $(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Code Coverage was $CoveragePercent percent, which is below the defined threshold."         
        $Host.SetShouldExit(10000)
    }
    ELSE 
    {
        Write-Output "$(Get-Date –f $timeStampFormat) - Code Coverage was $CoveragePercent percent, which is above the defined threshold.
    }
}`

Works great! :)